# Why has not working in CSS [select parent]

Tags: css, reference, parent

I am developing a web page and I need select "parent of" another element but not working and also it not working in a simple page as this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="">
  <a href="#" class="prueba">prueba!</a>
</div>
<style media="screen">
  div:has(.prueba) {
    border: solid 2px red;
  }
</style>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I use div in style section, working, but I need catch div with the first child, in this case "a" (class prueba) but not working for me.

Thank you!

Comment: as a side note the selector is wrong, it should be `div:has( > .prueba)`

Comment: Not working Temani Afif, thank you

Comment: it will not work because it's not yet supported, but your selector is wrong

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `:has()` selector is CSS4 and has almost no browser support yet (Jan 2019). You will need to use Javascript until support exists.

See [Can I Use - :has()](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has)

Comment: 2023 Q2+, as of Firefox v103 this is disabled by default.  From their dox: "From version 103: this feature is behind the layout.css.has-selector.enabled preference (needs to be set to true). To change preferences in Firefox, visit about:config." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Comment: This feature has over 80% adoption as of September 2023 per the link in this answer. And :has() is *still* not working for me in Chrome. Is there a way to delete this answer / reopen the question?

Comment: @MichaelG That's not how SO works. If you have a question start a new one and show your code.

Comment: It'll just get flagged as duplicate and shut down. If ChatGPT doesn't know the answer, it's easier to just give up than use SO.